# Why can't I remove a person from an array?

Tags: c, struct, fifo

I've been sitting with this code for three days. The problem is that I have reached the rock bottom and I don't know how I will solve this without any help from you guys. I have a struct with arrays of type char name, surname, persnbr.

```
  struct pers
{
    char name[7];
    char last_name[10];
    char id_nbr[12];

};
```

I have solved the problem with adding name surname and persnbr in the arrays but now I don't know how to remove them.

This is the queueEn function

```
 void queueEn(person p1){


    strcpy(queue[last].name, p1.name);
    strcpy(queue[last].last_name, p1.last_name);
    strcpy(queue[last].id_nbr, p1.id_nbr);



}
```

and the queueAdd function

```
 void queueAdd(person person1)
{
    if(last<MAX_SIZE_QUEUE){
        printf("Name: ");
        scanf("%s", person1.name);
        printf("Last name: ");
        scanf("%s", person1.sur_name);
        printf("Id-number: ");
        scanf("%s", person1.id_nbr);
        last++;
    }else {

        printf("Queue is full\n");
    }
    queueEn(person1);
}
```

This code works excellent.

Now I have the functions `queueDe` and `queueRemove`

This is what I've done so far:

```
 void queueDe(person *personPoint){
    first = (first + 1)% MAX_SIZE_QUEUE;
    *personPoint = queue[first];
    strcpy(personPoint->name, queue[first].name);
    strcpy(personPoint->last_name, queue[first].last_name);
    strcpy(personPoint->id_nbr, queue[first].id_nbr);
}
```

The thing is that I have to copy the information from array so I assumed that's how you do it. The information will be shown to the user(the person who is the last on the queue(FIFO-structure))

Here is the function `remove_from_queue`

```
void queueRemove(person personRem){
    if(first < MAX_SIZE_QUEUE){

    printf("Name: %s", personRem.name);
    printf("Last Name: %s", personRem.last_name);
    printf("Id-Number: %s", personRem.id_nbr);
    first++;
    }else{
        printf("Queue is empty");
    }
    queueDe(&personRem);
}
```

The variables first and last are equivalent with the end of array and the beginning of array. To delete the last person in the array I have to delete the person on first. Both of the variables are initialized to 0 in the beginning. I've read that I need to initialize the pointer *personPoint to malloc but I don't know how to use it in this specific situation.

When I execute the program and want to delete the person nothing happens.

I'm thankful for an answer.

Comment: So basically you are trying to do queue with statically sized array? Clear that, because probably there won't be many people willing to read your whole post.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you exactly mean by that? How do I make it dynamically?

Comment: Again, clear what you're trying to do, what problems you're facing. What do you want from people that read your question.

Comment: @Eskipo create a linked list. `struct node{ node *next, *prev; person data };`

Comment: I have to remove the information from an array name, lastname, id_nbr. To do that I have used the functions queueDE and queueRemove. The queueEN and queueAdd works fine.@clcto I have to use struct and arrays no linked list.

Comment: And what's queueDE, queueRemove? What's the problem with them? Your funtion names tell me nothing without you specifying what you want them to do. Why there are 2 functions for (apparently) the same action?

Comment: @zubergu the queueDE is used to remove the person in the position for variable head. The information for the deleted person is to be copied to the person variable that the parameter points to. In the queueRemove function I have to first control so queue is not empty then I have to create a person variable which I have to call queueDe with. Or the opposite? At the end I have to print the information.

Comment: Well the problem with the problem is that the printf in the function queueRemove doesn't show anything. And I'm not sure how strcpy is used  in the function queueDe

Comment: Well, I'll try to look at my code tomorrow then.

Answer (score 1):

A circular queue is a reasonable data structure, but you need a clear grasp of your queue 'empty' and queue 'full' conditions.  First we will define a circular queue struct, which holds first, last and queue[] array elements,

```
typedef struct circular_array_queue_s
{
    person* queue[MAX_SIZE_QUEUE];
    int first;
    int last;
} CirQueue;
CirQueue cirq;
```

Now we can define functions to report whether the queue is empty, full, and to report the count of the number of elements,

```
int queueEmpty()
{
    if( cirq.first == cirq.last ) //queue empty
    {
        printf("Queue is empty");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int queueFull()
{
    if( ((cirq.last+1%MAX_SIZE_QUEUE)) == cirq.first ) //queue full
    {
        printf("Queue is full\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int queueCount()
{
    int count=0;
    if( cirq.first<=cirq.last )
        count=(cirq.last-cirq.first);
    else //if ( cirq.first>cirq.last )
        count=(cirq.last+MAX_SIZE_QUEUE)-cirq.first;
    return count;
}
```

The queue operations for enqueue and dequeue are simplified, as you enqueue at the queue last position, and dequeue from the queue first position.  Since you have a circular queue, moving the first and last indices is done by incrementing by one, and wrapping at the end (using modulus MAX_SIZE_QUEUE),

```
person*
queueEn(person* p)
{
    //err
    if( queueFull() ) { return NULL; } //queue full, fail
    cirq.queue[cirq.last] = p;
    cirq.last = (cirq.last+1)%MAX_SIZE_QUEUE; //one
    return p;
}
person*
queueDe()
{
    person* p;
    //err
    if( queueEmpty() ) { return NULL; } //queue empty, fail
    p = cirq.queue[cirq.first];
    cirq.queue[cirq.first] = NULL;
    cirq.first = (cirq.first+1)%MAX_SIZE_QUEUE;
    return p;
}
```

Walking (iterating) over the entire can be done using a function similar to,

```
person*
queueIterate()
{
    person* p;
    int iter;
    if( queueEmpty() ) { return NULL; } //queue empty, skip
    for( iter=cirq.first; iter!=cirq.last; iter=(++iter)%MAX_SIZE_QUEUE )
    {
        personPrint(p = cirq.queue[iter]);
    }
    return p;
}
```

Adding elements to the queue requires that you create elements to add (malloc), and properly dispose of elements when you remove them (free),

```
void queueAdd(person person1)
{
    if( queueFull() ) { return; } //queue full, cannot add
    personRead(&person1);
    person* p;
    queueEn(personCopy(p=personNew(),&person1));
}
person*
queueRemove(person* personRem)
{
    person* p;
    if(p = queueDe())
    {
        if(personRem) {
            personCopy(personRem,p); personDel(p);
        }
        //if you don't give a personRem, you must free person p removed from queue
        else
            personRem=p;
    }
    return personRem;
}
```

You want to test these queue functions,

```
int
main()
{
    person per;
    person* perp;
    int done=0;
    while(!done)
    {
        queueAdd(per);
        if( queueFull() ) done=1;
        if( queueCount() >= 3 ) done=1; //just do three
    }
    queueIterate();
    while(!queueEmpty())
    {
        personPrint(perp=queueRemove(&per));
    }
}
```

---

Please understand that C strings are null-terminated, so declaring your char[] using an N+1 idiom will clearly communicate the available string size,

```
typedef struct person_s
{
    char name[9+1];         //size to N+1, makes clear the space, "Alexander"(9)
    char last_name[10+1];   //room for null-terminator
    char id_nbr[12+1];      //you really want to room for null-terminator
} person;
```

You will find that having functions which encapsulate your member access can make your code more readable, and support a DRY (Dont Repeat Yourself) approach, and hide details which you probably do not want to expose and handle everywhere,

```
person*
personNew()
{
    person* pnew;
    if( !(pnew=malloc(sizeof(person))) ) return NULL;
    strncpy(pnew->name, ">name", sizeof(pnew->name));
    strncpy(pnew->last_name, ">last_name", sizeof(pnew->last_name));
    strncpy(pnew->id_nbr, ">id_nbr", sizeof(pnew->id_nbr));
    return(pnew);
}
void personDel(person* p)
{
    if( !p ) return; //fail, must have valid pointer
    free(p);
    return;
}
person*
personCopy(person* pd, person* ps)
{
    if(!pd || !ps) return;
    strncpy(pd->name, ps->name, sizeof(pd->name));
    strncpy(pd->last_name, ps->last_name, sizeof(pd->last_name));
    strncpy(pd->id_nbr, ps->id_nbr, sizeof(pd->id_nbr));
    return(pd);
}
```

Here are functions to set the member values (often called setters or mutators),

```
person*
personName(person* p1, char* name)
{
    if(!p1 || !name) return p1;
    strncpy(p1->name, name, sizeof(p1->name));
    return(p1);
}
person*
personLastName(person* p1, char* last_name)
{
    if(!p1 || !last_name) return p1;
    strncpy(p1->last_name, last_name, sizeof(p1->last_name));
    return(p1);
}
person*
personIdNbr(person* p1, char* id_nbr)
{
    if(!p1 || !id_nbr) return p1;
    strncpy(p1->id_nbr, id_nbr, sizeof(p1->id_nbr));
    return(p1);
}
```

And here are functions to read and print your person struct,

```
person*
personRead(person* personp) //two
{
    if(!personp) return personp;
    //you really should allow for more space here
    char name[99+1];
    char last_name[99+1];
    char id_nbr[99+1];
    printf("Name: ");        scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Last name: ");        scanf("%s", last_name);
    printf("Id-number: ");        scanf("%s", id_nbr);
    personName(personp,name);
    personLastName(personp,last_name);
    personIdNbr(personp,id_nbr);
    return(personp);
}
void personPrint(person* personp) //five
{
    if(!personp) return personp;
    printf("Name: %s,", personp->name);
    printf("Last Name: %s,", personp->last_name);
    printf("Id-Number: %s\n", personp->id_nbr);
}
```

*Note that I used malloc/free and person* (pointer to person struct) throughout.  You need to learn about pointers if you want to program in C.*